# Can a function parameter have more than one default value?

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, default

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    def func(text=i):
        print(text)
    tkinter.Button(root, command=func).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code defines a new function every time the loop runs. But after the loop ends, shouldn't func only refer to the last function defined with text having the default value of 4. All the command options for all the buttons point to the same functions but still the defaults are different. Why?

Comment: Although you use same name in the for loop, but they have different reference values (pointer addresses) which you can show by adding `print(id(func))` after the function declaration.  So the command option is bind to different function for each button actually.

Comment: I added print(id(func)) after print(text) in func. The id for all the functions seems to be the same.

Comment: No you should put the statement before `tkinter.Button(...)`, not inside `func()` function.

Comment: If the command is bound to different functions, shouldn't doing what I did also print different ids

Comment: No, the id of last `func` will be printed if the statement is put inside `func` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a function parameter have more than one default value?

Yes, it can have as many as you want.

> But after the loop ends, shouldn't func only refer to the last function defined with text having the default value of 4.

No, because you create a new function in each iteration of the loop. Each time `def func` is called inside the loop, a new function is called.